# How to continue training for a saved and then loaded Keras model?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Following the [official keras documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)  , I was able to save and load a model. Keras is using tensorflow as the backend.

However, is it possible to run more training for such saved and loaded models.

Following is the code borrowed from [Link](http://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/). Then edited.

In the following code, the model is trained for 75 epochs and saved then loaded again.

However, when I tried to train it further with more 75 epochs it seems model was not trained and I got the same result without any modifications.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json
import numpy
import os
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.txt", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=75, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file: json_file.write(model_json)

# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("model.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

# later...

# load json and create model
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

# evaluate loaded model on test data
loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))


model.fit(X, Y, epochs=75, batch_size=10, verbose=0)
score = loaded_model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (loaded_model.metrics_names[1], score[1]*100))
```

Comment: Don't use `save_weights()` and `load_weights()` along with `Adam`. These functions save only the model weights, but not the optimizer. Use `model.save()` and `load_model()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from that code that your evaluating the `loaded_model` twice, but your extra training is done on just the `model`. Instead of copying and pasting different variable names you could try something like this... I find it a little easier to keep track of. Also, add some white space to your code between comments, it will help keep things clear and organized.

```
# Save a model you have trained
model.save('trained_model.h5')

# Delete the model
del model

# Load the model
model = load_model('trained_model.h5')

# Train more on the loaded model
model.fit(data, labels, epochs, batch_size)
```

Comment: That, plus the use of `model.save`, which additionally saves the training configuration and the state of the optimizer.